# Multiple Inputs in BPEL Process

Tags: bpel, orchestration, apache-ode

I just started developing BPEL a few weeks ago, and I use Eclipse Designer and Apache ODE. I have a use case where the user needs to insert multiple inputs but instead of editing the schema for the first receive input, I require that the user first inputs a number, than I process and after the reply I need the user to make another input, is this at all possible in BPEL since I need to stop the process to receive another input.

Also I have found in the ODE documentation that BPEL does not support array variables, does it mean that from BPEL I cannot return an array object (http://ode.apache.org/copy-with-insert-attribute.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BPEL supports any XSD datatypes and constructs, thus you can model array-style variable with xsd sequences. Standard BPEL however is not good at inserting values into such an array. The standard compliant way is to use a XSLT script that adds a value to the array. But most BPEL engines provide XPath extensions (like the one you mentioned) that makes that easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that insight on BPEL arrays as you solved my problem in that area. However my more pressing problem is that I require input in the middle of my BPEL. I have checked the BPEL4People Extension but do not know if it suits my needs, as what I require is for the BPEL to 'pause' for the user letting him select/input data into the BPEL, would help me a lot if you can give me some pointers in that area. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to wait for a user or for a webservice call?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I need a user input, not a webservice call. Thanks

Comment: For user inputs BPEL4People/WSHT is the standard way, however it is not supported by Apache ODE.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use BPEL4People, but the engine that I used (WSO2 BPS) needed a human artifact with the addition of JSPs for the task engine, and since I need my output to be in XML, it did not suite my need, but thanks again for the help.

Comment: Just a thought hanging in my head...but can I modify the Apache ODE source code available to make it wait for a user input? This is just an idea and therefore might not even be possible.....

Comment: This is pretty difficult as this is not intended by the architecture. You would better implement a webservice that handles such a user input and the sends the user's input back to the BPEL process.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your insight, what do you mean by implementing a webservice that handles the user input? Thanks

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what kind of user input you have in mind I can only guess. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: well let say its a simple system where first you enter a priority, High, Low etcc... and u invoke a webservice which gets all issues with that priority, then I display the return xml, where the user can enter the Issue ID to delete/modify that issue, therefore he first needs to insert the priority, after selecting which issue he needs to input the issue ID. That's something on the basis that I require. Thanks

Comment: @Vanto Any response to the last comment? I need to do the same.